# Make a href below p

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my `#supportHelp a` show below my `supportHelp h2` on my `@media only screen and (max-width: 321px)`

This is what it looks like:
[image]

CSS:

```css
#supportHelp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#supportHelp h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#supportHelp p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#supportHelp a {
  background-color: #cc293f;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="supportHelp">

<h2>Need more information? Get in touch <a href="http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/support" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></h2> 
<p>We are always here to assist, contact us via e-mail, social media or our live chat.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the media query set the `a` to `display:block;` and remove the left margin:

```css
#supportHelp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  }
  #supportHelp h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #supportHelp p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  }

  #supportHelp a {
  background-color: #cc293f;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 321px) {
  #supportHelp a {
    margin-left:0;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="supportHelp">

<h2>Need more information? Get in touch <a href="http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/support" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></h2> 
<p>We are always here to assist, contact us via e-mail, social media or our live chat.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [APAD1's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35488940/211627), I tried `display: block`, but as a block element its width increased to 100%.

After some fiddling with this idea, I used `display: inline-block` which resulted in the same width as the intended design with the added benefits of block layout. Finally, I used `margin-left` to align it properly.

Comment: Yours didn't show up whilst I was posting my answer, apologies.

Comment: No problem. I misread your post. I think your answer is fine. Don't forget to use voting to show appreciation.

Comment: No worries at all, upvoted the ones that are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to supportHelp a:

float:left;
width: 100%;

And in case put there a max-width if you want to limit the width

Answer (score 0):

> Align according to your requirement margin-left:30px; margin-top:10px;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #supportHelp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  }
  #supportHelp h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  #supportHelp p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  }

  #supportHelp a {
  background-color: #cc293f;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="supportHelp">

<h2>Need more information? Get in touch <br><br><a href="http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/support" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></h2> 
<p>We are always here to assist, contact us via e-mail, social media or our live chat.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline-block;` on the anchor tag to give it its own margin, padding, etc.

(When you run the snippet, click the "Full Page" button so that you can resize the window.)

```css
#supportHelp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#supportHelp h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#supportHelp p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#supportHelp a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cc293f;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="supportHelp">

<h2>Need more information? Get in touch <a href="http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/support" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a></h2> 
<p>We are always here to assist, contact us via e-mail, social media or our live chat.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey! I actually just posted my answer and used inline-block when I was fiddling with the code, thanks for the help though :)